# How can I view the classpath and jvm args of an executing java program in windows

Tags: java, windows, process, jvm

In *nix I just do `ps -ef | grep java` to see the jvm args and classpath of an executing java program. How can I see it in windows command prompt? I want to see if certain jars are actually in the classpath of a running weblogic server.

Answer (score 19):

From the command line I would use

> jinfo < pid >

which will give you this information and more

Answer (score 9):

You can write a small application to connect via JMX and query the mbean java.lang.Runtime. It has an attribute "ClassPath".

```
import java.lang.management.*

ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getClassPath()
```

Comment: It is awesome that you can even do this in a debug session using watch parameters.

Answer (score 7):

You can fire up [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), connect to the JVM running Weblogic and then navigate to the "VM Summary" tab to inspect the classpath/vm args.

Comment: This was specifically to know if it can be can be done via command prompt in windows.

Comment: [jmxterm](http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/) can be used to query the appropriate mbean for classpath.